# d3.js how to set y-axis fixed position

Tags: d3.js

I just got this nice chart here

https://jsfiddle.net/eo8223ay/1/

```
<body>
    <div id="chart1" class="chart"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

But the problem is when I scroll x axis , the y axis disappeared.
I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156887/d3-js-line-chart-axis-with-fixed-position) but no luck.
[The solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762688/d3-make-y-axis-position-fixed-even-the-scroller-x) looks great but it wont work on my example.

I know axis in d3 are actually svg , so how do I achieve of that a fixed y-axis ?

Comment: My answer here may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43712482/5768908

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

        function myFunction() {
            if(window.pageYOffset == 0)
            {
                d3.select("#test").nodes()[0].setAttribute("transform", "translate(200, " + 10  +")")
            }
             if (window.pageYOffset > 0) {
              d3.select("#test").nodes()[0].setAttribute("transform", "translate(200, " + window.pageYOffset  +")")
}
}
```

Comment: Some little description of your code will be helpful and make your answer more clear, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and improve quality of the answer